# Pandas queries to SQL queries (Python equivalent to R's dplyr)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dplyr, translate

### Question

At my company people would like to build dataframe/table queries in Python as the Python syntax is often much more clear and easier to work with than SQL queries as you can chain together your operations.

In **R** it easy to translate between R dataframe operations and SQL because of the **tidyverse** and **dplyr** libraries. Is there anything similar in Python?

### Example of what I want (written in R)

Here I show in **R** what I would like to be able to do in Python/Pandas, which is basically 1) place data in database, 2) make fancy dataframe operations, 3) carry out those operations in database.

```
# Importing library
library(dplyr)

# Connecting to database
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), 
    host = "database.rstudio.com",
    user = "hadley",
    password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
)

# Placing some data in the database
copy_to(con, nycflights13::flights, "flights",
    temporary = FALSE, 
    indexes = list(
      c("year", "month", "day"), 
      "carrier", 
      "tailnum",
      "dest"
    )
  )
```

Now to the "hard" problem I would like to perform in Python.

```
# Making fancy operations on data using tidyverse chaining
tailnum_delay_db <- flights_db %>% 
    group_by(tailnum) %>%
    summarise(
        delay = mean(arr_delay),
        n = n()
    ) %>% 
    arrange(desc(delay)) %>%
    filter(n > 100)

# Getting SQL code to perform same operation!!!!
tailnum_delay_db %>% show_query()

> <SQL>
> SELECT `tailnum`, AVG(`arr_delay`) AS `delay`, COUNT(*) AS `n`
> FROM `flights`
> GROUP BY `tailnum`
> HAVING (COUNT(*) > 100.0)
> ORDER BY `delay` DESC
```

### Example in Pandas

Let's try to do the same in Pandas, where we just make some more simple data.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# Creating a local Pandas DataFrame with some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,20,30,40,50,60], 'B': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']})

# Connecting to database
conn = sqlite3.connect('test_database')
c = conn.cursor()

# Writing dataframe to database
df.to_sql('df', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
```

So far so good! Next I make some "fancy" pandas operations that I want to translate to SQL.

```
# Making a groupby
df.groupby('B').mean().reset_index()
```

Now, is there any way to get the SQL for carrying out this operation?

### The Obvious Solution (which I am NOT looking for)!

One could just:

1. Read SQL data into Pandas Dataframe
2. Make transformations in Pandas locally
3. Write Pandas Dataframe to SQL table

But I don't want to pull ALL my data into Python because I have memory constraints. I would e.g. like to read 1000 lines, build my fancy and complicated query, translate it to SQL and the execute the SQL query remotely on the database.

Comment: Write the SQL code and pass it to `pd.read_sql_query`. Another option is to use the `ibis` library

Comment: Well, then I would have to write the insane SQL queries, which is what I want to avoid, thus this post ;)

Comment: i wouldnt call them insane. anyways have a look at the [ibis project](https://ibis-project.org/)

Comment: If you see the ones at my company where queries of several hundred lines are made, then you would think they were insane :) I think Ibis looks pretty cool. Hope it mature enough for more advanced pandas queries! Have you tried it out? If you post it as an answer I will upvote, and then if no other suggestions are in by tomorrow, I will accept the answer :)

Comment: lol ... all good. yes i have tried it out. it is quite a mature library with support for several database backends.

Comment: Cool, if you make a post, I will accept it :)